# when and how to appropriately use /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Tags: linux, performance, redhat

You can clear page cache with /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches. Can someone provide a practical explanation of how this works, when as a sysadmin you would want to do this, how to determine if your system needs it, and a real-world example of how to apply this knowledge?

Comment: Approximately never. Unless you want to wind up [here](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Modern-Memory-Management.aspx).

Comment: Only in testing and you want some benchmarks for a 'fresh' read of data from disk.

Comment: I do this when I'm restarting MySQL on systems with large innodb buffer pools.  That combined with a few other features allows you to more evenly distribute NUMA memory allocations across nodes.  The *flush caches* option does exactly that.  Outside of that, pretty much never.  [Improved NUMA support in Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/performance/innodb_numa_support.html).

Comment: It can be useful to reduce memory fragmentation.  SUSE recommends it to attempt to relieve memory pressure:  https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/sles-1112-os-tuning-optimisation-guide-part-1/